# Go switch vs if-else efficiency

Tags: go, switch-statement, if-statement

In Go, `switch`es are much more flexible than in C (and C++) since they can handle cases of boolean expressions and replace large `else`-`if` ladders seemingly entirely, especially with the default `switch {...}` blocks.

```
switch {
    case x < 5 && y > 2:
        //...
    case y == 1 || x > 2:
        //...
    default:
}
```

Is there any efficiency advantage to using a `switch` over `else`-`if` in Go?  It seems that the boosted efficiency would be lost by the `switch`'s flexibility.  Is it just up to the compiler to figure it out and see if it can make a jump table?

Is there any performance advantage to using `switch` over `if` and `else`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless all your `case` are integral constants then you lose the possibility of transforming the `switch` to a jump-table.

So, at best, Go's `switch` might be equivalent to C++'s `switch` if you only use integral constants, but otherwise it will be no more efficient than `if/else`.

Answer (score 14):

It's completely up to the compiler to figure it out and choose a good implementation strategy for your code. You can always find out what code the compiler is generating by requesting an assembly listing of the compiler output. See the [`-S` option](http://golang.org/cmd/gc/) to the Go compiler.

Answer (score 5):

It's surely irrelevant for your application performance. There is probably other more complex situation where you can improve performance. Like saving a single SQL query is probably like 1 million if/else/switch.

Do not worry much about detail like that and focus on higher level stuff.

Comment: This is a really helpful response.  Thanks for telling me to disregard the question, I get it now.

Comment: As with all optimisations, they should be guided by measurements and analysis rather than fretting about details that may never have any impact. But if your switch/case is deeply nested in an inner loop, its behaviour may possibly be highly significant. As I said, measurement and analysis are needed.